# Cypress exiting while downloading file in new tab

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am working on a React-based application that has a download button. On clicking the button application is opens a new tab and downloads the file. Since Cypress can not handle the new tab it failing altogether. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please share your code and also the errors (if you're getting any).

Comment: @AlapanDas I looked into application code, it is written in react has an attribute as onClick=downloadFile. In downloadFile function, windows.open("ur"l, "_blank") is used which is downloading a file by opening new tab and updating a flag which is later used in the application.  Not sure if CYpress allow to call different application function in application code